# How to eliminate "strange effect" CSS (picture inside)

Tags: html, css

When I place heading in container (in this case modal) - there is like small white vertical borders. How to eliminate them and keep the same HTML structure?

[Link on CodePen](https://codepen.io/khristomifort/pen/JwQRQy)

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal__heading">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Image with an issue]

Comment: Tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on macOS and don't have these borders. What are you using?

Comment: maybe because you fixed it already? better to use the functionality in stackoverflow, so future people who might come across this question see the problematic code. if you update/fix your pen in codepen, it's no longer comprehensible because the code is updated on another site.

Comment: @maysi I am using the same thing. `:)`

Comment: @maysi It happens in chrome on two different PCs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by `transform`. You have to fix it by using the following rule on the `transform`ed element:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Demo:** [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BvgQZB)

Some more information here: [backface-visibility](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/).

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your answer.  But tips of the top left and right corners are still shining through with white color though. 
It seems like there's no complete cure for this kinda issue. So I will just change a HTML structure a bit ans CSS accordingly.

Comment: @EugeneChristo Thanks for the find mate. Yep, blame the rendering engine. They aren't still perfect... Feel free to update my answer if you need. Happy to take up the edits.